# How can i deploy specific change set via Release management?

Tags: visual-studio, release-management

I have created a database solution in visual studio. All the objects (Stored procedures + Tables) are linked to this solution with their build action as '**Build**'.
When i am trying to deploy this solution via RM, A **dacpac** file is generated which will deploy complete solution with all the objects.

Is there any way to deploy only particular objects/change set using Release Management?

Comment: Can you provide an example of why you'd want to do this?

Comment: Lets say two teams are working on the same solution, but different objects. Now both have committed their changes in TFS. But while publishing the changes of Team 1, Team 2 changes should not be deployed via RM. This is the specific scenario i am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which flavour/version of RM you are using but the general advice is the same, which is that you need to think of RM as a tool that works *with* the capabilities of other tools rather than a tool that *extends* the capabilities of other tools. If the tools you want RM to work *with* can do the task via the command line or build your desired output then RM can almost certainly harness that capability and deploy your bits.

As a staring point I would leave RM out of the equation and focus on whether SSDT and/or your build system can deliver the desired results, then move on to configuring RM to carry out the deployment.